# Ruby Prawn - Determine the width of a mono spaced font

Tags: ruby, fonts, prawn

I'm trying to overlay polygons on top of a grid of mono-spaced characters.  In order to calculate the coordinates for the polygons I need to know how wide a single character is.  How do you determine the width of a single mono-spaced (Courier 12) character using the Ruby Prawn gem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According [to this](http://samesystem.posterous.com/prawn-tip-get-text-width) there is a `width_of` method buried in Prawn:

```
pdf.width_of(text, :size => 10)
```

[Here](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Document.html#method-i-width_of) is a bit more documentation I was able to dig up. In terms of your question I think you would do:

```
pdf.width_of('a', :size => 12) #provided a was the single character in question
```